# proper way to configure d3 to work with angular2 and typescript

Tags: d3.js, typescript, angular

trying to include d3 library into an angular2 typescript project. I added d3 via `npm install d3` and the typings via `typing install d3 --save`, the project local server doesn't start (`tsc && concurrently "npm 
run tsc:w" "npm run lite"`), with the following error:

```
typings/browser/definitions/d3/index.d.ts(3319,1): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/browser/definitions/d3/index.d.ts(3323,1): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/browser/definitions/d3/index.d.ts(3327,1): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/modules/d3/index.d.ts(3319,1): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/modules/d3/index.d.ts(3323,1): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/modules/d3/index.d.ts(3327,1): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

these are my config files:

typings.json:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#5c182b9af717f73146399c2485f70f1e2ac0ff2b",
    "gapi": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2.d.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "registry:npm/d3#3.0.0+20160211003958"
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "session-explorer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10",
    "d3": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you need to exclude your typings main.d.ts and main directories.

I would suggest adding a tsconfig.json in the same directory where your typings.json file is located.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main.d.ts",
      "typings/main"
  ]
}
```

The [angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html) has a good introduction on how the tsconfig.json file works.

Comment: thanks @drinck, actually I someway got rid off the error by deleting the typings and node_modules folder and repeating the installation, but then I got more errors, last of them the browser tried to get "d3/index" via ajax, with error 400 (when using `import * as d3 from 'd3/index';`). finally, what worked for me was more like a hack: include the d3.js file in the index.html and declaring a `var d3: any` in the component ts file..

Answer (score 33):

You can now install typings as follows:

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

Then you can import d3 as follows

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Answer (score 15):

**The 2017 Update**

***Installation***

Installing types for d3 **v3**:

```
npm install d3@3.x --save
npm install @types/d3@3.x --save-dev
```

Installing types for the latest d3 version (at the moment of writing **v4**):

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

***Usage***

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Answer (score 5):

As there is no typings available for D3 V4, we have to manually declare the d.ts for d3 some thing like

```
declare function d3(string: any): any;
```

After installing the D3 node module, we can import in file as

```
var d3: any = require('d3');
```

Comment: Great, it works with the last version of angular-cli (the one where System lib has been removed) !!!

Comment: @Petah now typings is available for d3 (npm install @types/d3) you can use that

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to import d3 directly with :

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

as long as the typings have been properly installed (which seems to be your case) and the actual d3.js file is loaded, either with a manual import or through some preprocessing task using node_modules/d3 folder.

Also make sure that d3.js is not accidentally imported in 4.x version, as this version brings many changes that have not been integrated in the dt typings as of today.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many different answers here. Because the maintain status of Typed d3.

For now, 2017/12/09, there is already d3 type, with latest version 4.12.0. So no need to downgrade to version 3.x, or declare something.